# ImportError from python-fitbit

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the python-fitbit package with Python 3.4 to get information from Fitbit (https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit).

Whenever I run it, I get the following error.  Right now oauthlib is installed, and I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling it to no avail. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/fitbit/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>

    from .api import Fitbit, FitbitOauth2Client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/fitbit/api.py", line 12, in <module>

    from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2, OAuth2Session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

    from .oauth1_auth import OAuth1
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_auth.py", line 6, in <module>

    from oauthlib.common import extract_params
ImportError: No module named 'oauthlib'
```

Answer (score 0):

Where in your file system did you install oauthlib?

Please make sure that oauthlib is in your python path.
In order to check your python path you can execute:

```
import sys; print sys.path
```

Comment: It returned a list:

'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
'/home/steven/PycharmProjects/howareyou', 
'/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
'/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages'

Comment: In which folder did you install oauthlib? Is it in the path?

Comment: I installed in in the dist-packages folder with pip.  I can see it in the folder too

Comment: It looks like when I import requests_oauthlib I still get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/steven/PycharmProjects/howareyou/questions.py", line 4, in <module>

    import requests_oauthlib

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

    from .oauth1_auth import OAuth1

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_auth.py", line 6, in <module>

    from oauthlib.common import extract_params
ImportError: No module named 'oauthlib'

Comment: Is it possible that the problem related to 32bit vs 64bit compatible? which version of python do you have? You can check it using the following python code: "import struct;print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))"